# How can I import an Excel file in an Unity WebGL game?

Tags: unity, webgl, file

Currently, we have a project that runs on Windows and uses an Excel spreadsheet to save/retrive some data/information. Now we want to build that project for WebGL. The problem is that file reading support is not available on the WebGL platform.  How do I solve this problem? Do I need to write a backend or there another way to use excel in WebGL platform even though the file reading API of the .NET framework is not supported on WebGL?

Answer (score 1):

When your WebGL game needs to read an arbitrary file, then you can add it to the game build by turning it into a [text asset](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextAsset.html). You need to rename it to give it the file extension `.bytes`, so Unity recognizes it as a binary file (for example: `items.xlsx.bytes`). To ensure that the file is included in the WebGL build, you need to store it in an [Assets/Resources](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html) folder or in an [asset bundle](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html) which you then export to your WebGL build.

If you decided to use resources:

```
TextAsset txt = Resources.Load("items.xlsx") as TextAsset;
```

If you decided to use an asset bundle:

```
AssetBundle bundle = myLoadedAssetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "myassetBundle"));
TextAsset txt = bundle.Load("items.xlsx", typeof(TextAsset)) as TextAsset;
```

Now you can get the binary data from that text asset with

```
byte[] bytes = txt.bytes;
```

and feed it into the code you already have for parsing Excel workbooks.

Comment: You can also reference your `TextAsset` directly via a public or serialized member variable on a `MonoBehaviour` or `ScriptableObject`, to access it without the `Resources.Load` or `AssetBundle` steps. In the past, I've also exported the Excel files to .csv to parse in the game as text strings from `TextAsset.text`